# WPF - Display Concatenated String in the ComboBox Items

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

I am creating WPF App using C#. I am trying to load items from `List<Customer>` inside combo box. I did the following:

```
 customersList = context.Customers.Where(c => c.IsDeleted == false).ToList<.Customer>().OrderBy(x => x.CustomerId);
 cmbCustomer.ItemsSource = customersList;
 cmbCustomer.DisplayMemberPath = "FirstName";
 cmbCustomer.SelectedValuePath = "CustomerId";
```

I was able to display FirstName of Customer Inside Combo box. **However, I wanted to display combination of First name and Last name of customers**. Following is my Customer Entity class

```
[Table("Customer")]
    public class Customer
    {
        [Key]
        public int CustomerId { get; set; }
        [Column("FirstName", TypeName = "ntext")]
        [MaxLength(100)]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        [Column("LastName", TypeName = "ntext")]
        [MaxLength(100)]
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        [Column("Email", TypeName = "ntext")]
        [MaxLength(100)]
        public string Email { get; set; }
        [Column("Company", TypeName = "ntext")]
        [MaxLength(100)]
        public string Company { get; set; }
        [Column("Phone", TypeName = "ntext")]
        [MaxLength(100)]
        public string Phone { get; set; }
        [Column("Address", TypeName = "ntext")]
        [MaxLength(500)]
        public string Address { get; set; }
        [Column("IsDeleted", TypeName = "bit")]
        public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do like this:

```
          var customersList = (from c in context.Customers
                                where c.IsDeleted == false
                                select new
                                {
                                    Name = c.FirstName + " " + c.LastName,
                                    c.CustomerId
                                }).ToList();

     cmbCustomer.ItemsSource = customersList;
     cmbCustomer.DisplayMemberPath = "Name";
     cmbCustomer.SelectedValuePath = "CustomerId";
```

I'm writing here. So my code may have error. Sorry about that.

Comment: its not working!! I am getting exception: Data binding directly to a store query (DbSet, DbQuery, DbSqlQuery, DbRawSqlQuery) is not supported. Instead populate a DbSet with data, for example by calling Load on the DbSet, and then bind to local data. For WPF bind to DbSet.Local. For WinForms bind to DbSet.Local.ToBindingList(). For ASP.NET WebForms you can bind to the result of calling ToList() on the query or use Model Binding, for more information see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=389592.

Comment: Found it the ToList() part was missing!! :) 
Updating this answer to the correct version!!

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to edit your entity class (another cleaner option is to have a separate customer view model class) you can add the following property:

```
public string FullName {
   get {
      return FirstName + " " + LastName;
   }
}
```

Then for your display member path:

```
cmbCustomer.DisplayMemberPath = "FullName";
```

You might also want to consider using XAML bindings rather than manually doing the binding in code behind, just a thought! Hope that helps.